# Are there known issues with Excel 2010 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 11?

Tags: excel, office-interop

I have a click once app that uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 11.0.5530 that has been working fine on all the deployments that had Excel 2007.

I have received an error report from a user that has a new Windows 7 machine with a fresh install of Excel 2010, and he's getting the following error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

So this is a desktop with a fresh install of Office 2010. Most errors I found by Googling with Bing were related to not having Office installed on the server, which is not in scope of this challenge.

Could there be a conflict between Excel 2010 and this version of Office Interop?

UPDATE: I was just informed the user has Office running through Citrix...so there's nothing really installed on the machine....sigh. Probably renders this question moot.

Answer (score 0):

The reference introp object must not be available on the system try referencing Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library